# Simple tokenization issue in NTLK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to tokenize the following text:

```
In Düsseldorf I took my hat off. But I can't put it back on.


'In', 'Düsseldorf', 'I', 'took', 'my', 'hat', 'off', '.', 'But', 'I', 
'can't', 'put', 'it', 'back', 'on', '.'
```

But to my surprise none of the [NLTK tokenizers work](http://text-processing.com/demo/tokenize/). How can I accomplish did? Is it possible to use a combination of these tokenizers somehow to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

You can take one of the tokenizers as a starting point and then fix the contractions (assuming that is the problem):

```
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordTokenizer

text = "In Düsseldorf I took my hat off. But I can't put it back on."
tokens = TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(text)

contractions = ["n't", "'ll", "'m"]
fix = []
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    for c in contractions:
        if tokens[i] == c: fix.append(i)

fix_offset = 0
for fix_id in fix:
    idx = fix_id - 1 - fix_offset
    tokens[idx] = tokens[idx] + tokens[idx+1]
    del tokens[idx+1]
    fix_offset += 1

print(tokens)
```

`>>>['In', 'Düsseldorf', 'I', 'took', 'my', 'hat', 'off', '.', 'But', 'I', "can't", 'put', 'it', 'back', 'on', '.']`

Comment: Great! Thanks. Do you think there are such instances apart from three you mentioned in contractions?

Comment: Here is a list of English [contractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_English_contractions)

Answer (score 1):

You should tokenize the sentence before tokenizing the words:

```
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> text = "In Düsseldorf I took my hat off. But I can't put it back on."
>>> text = [word_tokenize(s) for s in sent_tokenize(text)]
>>> text
[['In', 'D\xc3\xbcsseldorf', 'I', 'took', 'my', 'hat', 'off', '.'], ['But', 'I', 'ca', "n't", 'put', 'it', 'back', 'on', '.']]
```

If you want to get them back into a single list:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> text = "In Düsseldorf I took my hat off. But I can't put it back on."
>>> text = [word_tokenize(s) for s in sent_tokenize(text)]
>>> text
[['In', 'D\xc3\xbcsseldorf', 'I', 'took', 'my', 'hat', 'off', '.'], ['But', 'I', 'ca', "n't", 'put', 'it', 'back', 'on', '.']]
>>> list(chain(*text))
['In', 'D\xc3\xbcsseldorf', 'I', 'took', 'my', 'hat', 'off', '.', 'But', 'I', 'ca', "n't", 'put', 'it', 'back', 'on', '.']
```

If you must put the `["ca", "n't"] -> ["can't"]`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest, chain
>>> tok_text = list(chain(*[word_tokenize(s) for s in sent_tokenize(text)]))
>>> contractions = ["n't", "'ll", "'re", "'s"]

# Iterate through two words at a time and then join the contractions back.
>>> [w1+w2 if w2 in contractions else w1 for w1,w2 in izip_longest(tok_text, tok_text[1:])]
['In', 'D\xc3\xbcsseldorf', 'I', 'took', 'my', 'hat', 'off', '.', 'But', 'I', "can't", "n't", 'put', 'it', 'back', 'on', '.']
# Remove all contraction tokens since you've joint them to their root stem.
>>> [w for w in [w1+w2 if w2 in contractions else w1 for w1,w2 in izip_longest(tok_text, tok_text[1:])] if w not in contractions]
['In', 'D\xc3\xbcsseldorf', 'I', 'took', 'my', 'hat', 'off', '.', 'But', 'I', "can't", 'put', 'it', 'back', 'on', '.']
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please the reason for doing? Your code doesn't seem to tackle the issue at hand. Check  "ca", "n' t" .